# Magento 2 Different Final Price Templates for Category and Product Page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have modified the final_price.phtml to customize the final price on the product page. It is working fine.
But I am getting the same customization on Category page which I do not want. Please let me know how can I use different final price templates for Product and Category pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps

**Step 1** for **configurable product** Create template file final_price.phtml file, in my case the file path is `app/design/frontend/{{companyname}}/{{themename}}/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$requestInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface');
$showaction = $requestInterface->getFullActionName();
?>
<?php if ($showaction == "catalog_product_view"): ?>
  /* your code */
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($showaction == "catalog_category_view"): ?>
  /* your code */
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Step 2** for  **simple product** create template file final_price.phtml at path `app/design/frontend/{{companyname}}/{{themename}}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$requestInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface');
$showaction = $requestInterface->getFullActionName();
?>
<?php if ($showaction == "catalog_product_view"): ?>
  /* your code */
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($showaction == "catalog_category_view"): ?>
  /* your code */
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Great answer. It worked for me. A little big fix "==" is needed.

Comment: @AhmadBaig now check it. fixed issue.

Comment: @AhmadBaig if it is working please accept my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses same final_price.phtml file all over the website to show prices. You can add your controller check on price to work around on product detail page.